# Chrome version 52.0.2743.116 position fixed/absolute issue

Tags: google-chrome

I updated from chrome 51.0.2704.106 to 52.0.2743.116. On earlier versions the page was working fine, but after update the position absolute and position fixed are not working as expected.

Can some help me on this? [link](https://www.wealthy.in/insights/)

Comment: So the issue was that if a div which is under flexbox is given position fixed/absolute. Please find the attached document

http://venturebeat.com/2016/07/20/chrome-52-arrives-with-new-developer-features-and-removes-the-app-launcher/